# split lines to Array items - for all files in dir - probably loops with bug

Tags: java, arraylist

Part of my homework.
I have written a method to split all words to ArrayList. Words are taken from all files in given project directory.
Unfortunately sometimes lines are skipped... and I wish to find the bug. Please help.
To specify: files are of 7 "words" separated with tabs in each line.

```
public class TravelData {
    static List<String> tour = new ArrayList<String>(); //lista zlokalizowana według nagłówka wiersza

    public TravelData(File dataDir) {
        String currentDirPath = new File(dataDir.toString()).getAbsolutePath();
        File currentDir = new File(currentDirPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = currentDir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

                try {
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(listOfFiles[i].toString()));
                    while (s.hasNextLine()){
                        ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(String value: s.nextLine().split("\t"))
                        {
                            line.add(value);
                        }
                        lineConverter(line, dbDate); //do something with grabbed data
                    }
                    s.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to find out where the bug is?

Comment: Note: I would never do `s.nextLine().split("\t")` instead i would take a new `String` array and assign it and then use it in for loop.

Comment: I have tried the debugger but currently my possibilities due to lack of sleep are reduced :( and I can not find where problem is, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: I did the second array as my first idea was(same result), then ended with this code.

Comment: Are you sure lines are skipped, or maybe there is a bug in your lineConverter method that you have not included here? A very simple test is to extract s.nextLine() into a variable and put a 'System.out.println(sNextLine)' before splitting

Comment: Also not entirely sure why you are creating new File instances from your dataDir - would dataDir.listFiles() not work?

Comment: Yes, File[] listOfFiles = dataDir.listFiles(); is enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally not used Scanners much, so I can't immediately spot the issue. But here is some old code using buffered file input stream that I've added your specific bits to:

```
public TravelData(File dataDir) {
    File[] listOfFiles = dataDir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            BufferedReader buffReader = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[i]);
                buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String fileLine = buffReader.readLine();
                while(fileLine != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(String value: fileLine.split("\t")) {
                        line.add(value);
                    }
                    lineConverter(line, dbDate);
                    fileLine = buffReader.readLine();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(buffReader != null) try { buffReader.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
                if(inputStream != null) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, I need to workaround the rest of code (problems with national letters)

Comment: If by national letters you mean extended characters that end up looking like weird symbols, you can set the character set in your InputStreamReader something like "new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.UTF8)" - check which charset you're meant to be using. Good luck!